# Reference Ids of inserted in testsetup records

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestClass {
    public static Id userId;
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        User u = createUser('userLastName');
        insert u;
        userId = u.Id;

        // creating an opportunity where owner of the opportunity would be the user created before
        System.runAs(u) {
            Opportunity opp = createOppty(u.Id);
            insert opp;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void testOpportunityOwnerIdIsCorrect() {
        // I want to use userId here, but it's null
        // So the following code would not work
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity];
        System.assertEquals(opp.OwnerId, userId);

        //instead, I have to select the user, resulting in additional unnecessary SOQL query. The following code will work:
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity];
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'userLastName'];
        System.assertEquals(opp.OwnerId, u.Id);
    }
}
```

In the code above, is it possible to get the Id of inserted  without selecting the user by name in a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC) for this to work, but I'm not sure we'll ever get to see it, unfortunately. For now, you need to re-query the records that were created during each unit test. testSetup's primary purpose is to reduce the time needed to start up each unit test by populating test records once before the tests start. You'll still realize a significant savings of deployment time, since records are only saved once per class, and you'll also enjoy a reduction of DML usage that you can then use for your unit tests, but you still need to use SOQL queries, unfortunately.

P.S. There's a bug in testSetup that causes your unit tests to have reduced governor limits based on whatever was consumed during testSetup (e.g. DML, SOQL, and CPU time). To avoid this bug, use Test.startTest() in your testSetup method:

```
@TestSetup
static void makeData(){
  Test.startTest();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @EvAzi this is the intended design:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC

Static vars are cleared before each test method, querying for the data from the testSetup method is the correct paradigm.

> We intentionally clear out static variables between each test method.  If we did not, each test would cease to be an independent trial. You could modify the static in one test method, which would make the order in which tests operate relevant to the results.  This is precisely what you don't want - data dependent tests.
>
> If you want information that is common to all tests, it can be
>   inserted in the test setup method and queried in each test method. 
>   The idea here is not to reduce the number of SOQL queries, it is to
>   reduce the amount of data being inserted into the system.  If you
>   insert 1000 records in test setup, run fifteen test methods, and you
>   run a query 15 times to get the 1000 records each time, that's still
>   less expensive (and faster) than inserting 1000 records 15 times.